# Get image byte/base64 from URL

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, base64, arrays

I'm looking for a solution where I can provide URL to specific image and then with Javascript I retrieve data of that image. I alread found that I can't just pull file through, so maybe byte array or base64 will do?

To be specific before someone downvote that question: I want to parse URL and get image to my server in any form. There is a lot similar questions, but none of them answers this one.

What I need that for? I have access to API where I also am provided with image url's, but I want them to be uploaded to my server via `Background Job` in Parse.com service (something like CRON job). I know how to link file with `ParseObject`, but can't find solution how to download image directly to `ParseCloud` and link it.

```
var Image = require("parse-image");
Parse.Cloud.job("getImagesJob", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var beerObj = Parse.Object.extend("My_class");
  var query = new Parse.Query(beerObj);
  query.first().then(function(objs) {
  var brew = objs.get("brewery");
  var bname = objs.get("beer_name");
  //var fullName = brew + " " + bname;
  var fullName = "Browar Name";
  console.log(fullName);

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api server address',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
      params: {
        q : fullName,
        client_id : '...',
        client_secret : '...'
    }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var json = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        if(json.meta.code === 200){
            if(json.response.beers.count > 0){

                if(json.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_label === "/default.png"){
                    console.log("brak etykiety dla " + fullName);

                } else {
                    console.log("znaleziono etykietę dla " + fullName);
                    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ //NOT REACHING
                      url: json.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_label,
                      success: function(response) {
                        // The file contents are in response.buffer.
                        var image = new Image();
                        return image.setData(response.buffer, {
                          success: function() {
                              objs.set("logo", image.data());
                            console.log("udalo sie dolaczyc");
                          },
                          error: function(error) {
                            // The image data was invalid.
                            console.error(error);
                          }
                        })
                      },
                      error: function(error) {
                        // The networking request failed.
                      }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                // daj cokolwiek żeby się nie zacięło na jednym

                console.log("Brak danych dla piwa: " + fullName);
            }       
        }

    }, function(httpResponse) {
      console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status + httpResponse.text);
    });

}).then(function(obj) {
  status.success("Zrobione");
}, function(error) {
  status.error(error);
});
});
```

Comment: console.log("znaleziono etykietę dla " + fullName); <<< This one was printed, right?

Comment: @Ralphilius yes, I already figured out how this all works. I had to put `httpRequest` in new `then()` promise. It took me a while, but it's working fine now. Thanks for that module snippet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parse-image` module in Cloud Code as in their [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-parse-image)

```
var Image = require("parse-image");

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: YOUR_URL,
  success: function(response) {
    // The file contents are in response.buffer.
    var image = new Image();
    return image.setData(response.buffer, {
      success: function() {
        console.log("Image is " + image.width() + "x" + image.height() + ".");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // The image data was invalid.
      }
    })
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // The networking request failed.
  }
});
```

With above code, you can get image data in Buffer using `image.data()`. To get base64 data, use `image.data().toString("base64")`

Comment: Wow, haven't foudn that before! Will that work with external source of image? i.e. "http://www.server.com/someimage.jpg" and it will get it?

Comment: Yes. Please mark as answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: please chceck my edited question - my code can't reach `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`. Everything else works properly (logs and everything).